# Apache resulta em Service Unavailable depois de instalar nginx e hhvm

Tags: apache, nginx, hhvm

Instalei o *Nginx* e o *HHVM* para testar a linguagem *Hack*.
Tudo perfeito, consigo programar em *Hack* e *PHP* utilizando esse conjunto.

Contudo, ao dar `stop` no *Nginx* e *HHVM* e `start` no **Apache 2** ele lança `Erro 503 Service Unavailable`.

No **error.log** ele lança isso:

> [Fri Mar 27 16:29:42.300830 2015] [proxy:error] [pid 26561]
>   (111)Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to
>   127.0.0.1:9000 (*) failed [Fri Mar 27 16:29:42.300853 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 26561] [client 127.0.0.1:58766] AH01079:
>   failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1

Alguém pode me ajudar?

(Utilizando Ubuntu 14.04)

EDIT:
Log e configurações conforme pedido nas perguntas:
http://pastebin.com/L5LnHKHf

Ao startar o apache
:/var/log/apache2$ sudo service apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2                                                  AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
 *

Comment: Abra um terminal (CTRL + Alt + T) e digite: `netstat -tulpn | grep 9000` o que aparece na tela?

Comment: Quando estou com nginx + hhvm: `tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      3614/hhvm`

Comment: Quando dou start no apache2 não aparece nada

Comment: Pelo que parece o [PHP-FPM](sudo service php5-fpm restart) não está em execução. Faça o seguinte abra o arquivo de configuração `gedit /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`, procure por uma linha que começa com `LISTEN` e mude para `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000`. **Salve**. Depois execute o comando: `sudo service php5-fpm restart`. Agora tente iniciar o Apache novamente.

Comment: Agora não está executando o nginx também, nem abre a página. no log de erro esta: `a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default~:21`

Comment: Meu arquivo de configuração é padrão: http://pastebin.com/zhFjEPzT

Comment: OBS: Não tenho o PHP-FPM instalado, não precisei rodar ele antes e nem depois da instalação, mas agora nenhum dos dois servers (apache dando o erro informado e o nginx+hhvm não inicia)

Comment: Ah sim, então desconsidere a mensagem acima e desfaça. Vou continuar procurando algo sobre.

Comment: @Raul3k, sobe os arquivos de configuração do Apache e do Nginx, e o Log do apache que teoricamente é `access_log`. Eu tenho alguns servidores em produção, inclusive Ubuntu e Debian, com nginx e apache. Com os arquivos dou uma debugada aqui pra vc. :D

Comment: @FernandoCordeiro Obrigado, o link com todos os arquivos está no final da pergunta, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muita pesquisa e com a ajuda do pessoal aqui finalmente consegui chegar a uma solução.

Ao instalar o HHVM ele já configurou o nginx e o apache, mas eu nao queria o apache trabalhando com o hhvm já que ele já esta carregando um modulo do PHP.

O Fernando Cordeiro me disse o seguinte:

> Agora eu antes de mais nada jogaria um arquivo estático em /var/www/web e testaria, algo tipo 127.0.0.1/arquivo.txt

Então me veio uma ideia que eu não tinha pensado antes: ver se existe o diretorio /etc/hhvm, e tem.

Dentro deste diretorio tem o arquivo `server.ini`. Dentro desse arquivo que eu descobri o porque de dar erro de comunicação em `127.0.0.1:9000` na seguinte linha:
`hhvm.server.port = 9000`

Então eu fui em `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/hhvm_proxy_fcgi.conf` que tem uma única linha:

`ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.(hh|php)(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/$1`

O que eu fiz foi somente comentar essa linha.

Agora quando eu starto o nginx eu trabalho com php+hack, quando starto o apache2 estou apto a trabalhar com o php5 que instalei.

Answer (score 1):

Raul, `duplicate default server` significa que seu arquivo de configuração tá bugado.

Sobre a confusão, coloca as configurações de ambos os servidores pra conferirmos.

Aproveitando a deixa: quem está usando a porta `9000` é o HHVM, não o PHP-FPM. Esse `error.log` não é do nginx? Tem o `error_log` do Apache?

Anexe o arquivo de configuração do Apache, e confirme se comentar ou remover essa entrada resolve o `duplicate default server (Não tenho certeza se ele atrela o ipv6 usando só a porta):

```
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
```

Se não resolver, confere se o `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` tem uma entrada `server { (...) }` com o `listen (...) default_server`. Se tiver, aí está seu erro. Ele tenta atrelar o nome `defauult_server` a dois `server {}` diferentes.

Comment: Olá, ao comentar não deu em nada, então comentei também a linha: `listen 80 default_server;` e funcionou o nginx. Então tentei trocar a porta para 8090 e agora o nginx está atrelado a porta 80 e a porta 8090. `listen 8090 default_server;
 #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;`

Comment: Remover ambos os `listen` desativa o bloco inteiro, então isso indica que deve existir um bloco `server` no `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` usando um `listen` com `default_server`. Sugiro remover do `nginx.conf` e deixar a configuração no `sites-enabled/default`, independe de qual código você vai colocar lá.

Comment: Olá, esse é o meu sites-enabled/default, é o unico arquivo que possui o bloco "server", perceba que eu retirei todos os 'listen': http://pastebin.com/WCJL4LvP

Comment: E o `hhvm.conf`? Se ele tiver um "listen" esse pode ser o motivo.

Os arquivos de configuração do nginx e do apache às vezes se tornam bastante caóticos, o segredo é entender a hierarquia e investigar o que está ocorrendo. Cada `include` significa mais um arquivo pra investigar, e um bom primeiro passo é entender a forma "padrão" de trabalhar com os arquivos pra evitar esse tipo de confusão. Por isso eu queria ver o conjunto dos arquivos, e ajudar a organizar, de forma a deixar mais claro como os principais comandos funcionam. :D

Comment: Só pontuar, no seu caso específico, o `listen` é o que define que esse bloco `server` vai responder ao navegador. Por isso simplesmente remover não é a solução. Precisamos entender porque ele deu o erro, para que a configuração funcione.

Comment: Na pergunta tem o link com todos os arquivos de conf. O hhvm.conf é este: http://pastebin.com/s0hVAnFr Eu não achei nenhum listen nele rsrs Pra mim ficou mto mais organizado do que nas versões anteriores rs

Comment: Não sei se é relevante mas: `PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp  open  ipp
3306/tcp open  mysql
5432/tcp open  postgresql
9000/tcp open  cslistener`

Comment: Confere se na pasta `/etc/nginx/conf.d` existe algum arquivo. Sugiro voltar o listen sem o `default_server` pois pode corrigir. Pelo erro do apache e pelo arquivo de configuração eu imagino que exista um arquivo de conf do apache em `sites-enabled/` (Dentro da pasta do apache) com a configuração, e possivelmente um ou mais arquivos em `mods-enabled/`. Algum desses arquivos fala que "php" vai pra porta `9000`. Mas como você deu `stop` no `hhvm` o apache fica sem resposta.

Comment: Em `/etc/nginx/conf.d` não há nenhum arquivo. Em `sites-enabled` tem um arquivo sim, o conteudo dele esta aqui: http://pastebin.com/ZeT336c5 . Em mods-enabled tem um monte de arquivos, http://pastebin.com/VVcNjqja

Comment: Falando na porta 9000 encontrei 2 arquivos: `/etc/nginx/hhvm.conf` conteudo: http://pastebin.com/s0hVAnFr e em `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled\hhvm_proxy_fcgi.conf` Conteudo: http://pastebin.com/AgskNrgc

Comment: Agora o Apache exibe a mensa `404 File Not Found` quando tento acessa-lo (127.0.0.1) enquanto o hhvm está ativado.

Comment: @Raul3k, o `hhvm_proxy_fcgi.conf` presume que o Site está em `/var/www`. A configuração do Apache aponta para qual pasta? (`apache/sites-enabled/*.conf`) É a pasta correta?

Comment: Quando ligo o nginx ele vai para `/usr/share/nginx/html`, funciona normalmente o php e hack nessa pasta. No Apache2 deveria estar apontando para /var/www/web `
dev1@dev1-MS-7636:/etc/apache2$ grep -ri /var/www/web *
sites-available/000-default.conf: DocumentRoot /var/www/web`. Bom, não sei onde mais ele estaria apontando senão para esta.

Comment: Em sites-enabled do nginx eu deixei somente `listen 8095;`, teoricamente ele deveria somente escutar a 8095 e não a 80, correto? Se sim, ele esta escutando as duas ainda.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22475/discussion-between-fernando-cordeiro-and-raul3k).